# I use php exec another php but this not working

Tags: php

i have this file:
**pippo.php**

```
exec(ExportExcel.php);
```

**ExportExcel.php**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php 
$stop=1;
......
php code
......
?>
```

The exec command runs the file but I don't know what it is doing. It remains hung up and I don't get to activate the breakpoint placed in the file.

Any idea?
Thnak's

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string to exec(), so maybe try `exec('./ExportExcel.php');`

---

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php